# Как подключиться к postgresql с sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://youuser:youpassword@localhost/youdb')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ASD": [0], "rtyer": [1]})
df.to_sql("users", engine)
```

Но возвращает ошибку `connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`

Как правильно подключиться к бд и сохранить в неё DataFrame?

Comment: а точно ли надо всю базу в дата фрейм? или достаточно будет таблицы в ней?

Comment: @Shilgen, отклонил правку, нужно сохранить датафрейм в таблицу в бд